# flash builder 4.6 Scaling Issue

Tags: flash-builder, flash-builder4.5, flashbuilder4

Can anyone explain me how to scale the image in canvas in flash builder 4.6, Scaling of image in component , can i get some examples ..  it should set almost all size screen

Answer (score 0):

Create a spark scale tag in fx declarations. And target the object of the canvas id you created and scale it by x and y components.

Something like this

s:scale target:{canvasid} scalex, scaley

mx:canvas id="canvasid"